# Json string field into Enum equivalent

Tags: java, json

A have a class that maps a json file , it looks something like this

```
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
 public class Account{
  ...
  @JsonProperty("status")
  private String status;
  ...
 }
```

and I have an `Enum` that represents the different status for the Account class

```
public Enum AccountStatus{

 BLO("BLO"),ACT("ACT"),PEN("PEN");
 private String status;

 private AccountStatus(String status){
  this.status = status;
 }
}
```

Is there a way to directly map the json property to the equivalent Enum in the `Account` class, to prevent using `AccountStatus.valueOf()` each time ?

What I did for now, I added a method in `Account` class

```
 public AccountStatus getAccountStatus(){
   return AccountStatus.valueOf(status);
 }
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Why don't you just use the enum class directly? @JsonProperty("status")
  private AccountStatus status;

Comment: If the string status of your enum values is exactly the same as the enum value's name, why do you need it in the first place? It doesn't seem like you're using it at all.

Comment: What about using moshi with a custom adapter? https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/README.md#custom-type-adapters

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
private String status;
```

To:

```
private AccountStatus status;
```

Jackson will automatically choose the correct `enum` value from the JSON-`status`-property